# How to render components inside a container in a page based on links pressed - ReactJs

Tags: reactjs, react-component

I have a page called `Teacher.js` which is supposed to hold content related to that teacher. I have a sidebar having different links like profile, information etc. I want if a user presses suppose profile, the profile component to load on the right side of the sidebar just any website would do. I am new to react. what should I do?

what I want more clearly:

[image: So I want if some presses suppose profile I want the profile component to render in the highlighted blue area where "this is the main content" is written]

So if someone presses suppose profile, I want the profile component to render in the highlighted blue area where "this is the main content" is written

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a routing library to your project, such as [react-router](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/overview). Then have the parent render the sidebar and the main content should be rendered using the router.

Inside the sidebar, each section should then just be a link to the correct route.

It would look something like this:

```
export const TeacherContainer = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Sidebar />
      <Routes>
        <Route path="profile" element={<TeacherProfile />}>
        <Route path="info" element={<TeacherInformation />}>
        // etc.
      </Routes>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: I understand routing. This side bar is present only in the Teacher(Parent in this case) component. I want to render TeacherProfile(children component) in that blue area

Comment: yup, that's exactly what you can do with routing. `Teacher` is the main route, whereas the other pages are nested routes. if you're using react-router, here's the [documentation](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/overview#nested-routes) for that.